# How to map style bgcolor into 3 parts color to all parts

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobile

Please Help, i want to ask how to repeat the UI 3 parts color in one long data

[image: this is mine]
[image: this is what i want]
this is my code now.

```
       <Card
            key={index}
            transparent
            style={globalStyle.borderRadius}
          >
            <CardItem
              style={
                index === 0 ? styles.creamStyle
                  : index === 1 ? styles.sweetStyle
                    : index === 2 ? styles.berryStyle : null
              }
            >
              <Left style={globalStyle.fdColl}>
                <Text style={styles.txtProduct}>{data.title}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.txtPrice}>{`Price start ${data.price}`}</Text>
              </Left>
              <Right>
                <Thumbnail source={data.image} style={{ width: '60%' }} />
              </Right>
            </CardItem>
          </Card>
```

Comment: replace `index === 0` with `index % 3 === 0` etc.

Comment: wahh, work for me..

thanks in advance